# SSIS 2012 - ConnectionString not using updated variable

Tags: variables, ssis, sql-server-2012

I've got a SSIS ConnectionString expression that's built using a couple of parameters and a variable.

My SQL procedure as an Output parameter that is passed to the variable using a OLE DB data source.

However, when the ConnectionString is built, it's still using the original variable value. It should be using the updated variable that is set via the SQL output parameter.

I've debugged this is break mode and can see my variable values change from the original value to the new value.

'Evaluate as Expression' is also set to TRUE on my variable.

I'm at a complete loss to explain what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Brian

Answer (score 0):

You should set `Evaluate as Expression` to False if you have the `expression` in your variables panel.

If `Evaluate as Expression` is set to True, then the expression in the `Variables` will be used all the time, otherwise, you need to set it to False if that variable could be overwritten during the execution.

Comment: My variable value and expression is empty at the start. I've set 'Evaluate as Expression' to false and I can see the variable value change in break mode. Ran it again and the ConnectionString is still using the original value of blank rather than the updated value set at runtime.

Comment: you only have that task to change the connection string?

Comment: No, I have an expression on my ConnectionString: @[$Package::ExtractToFolderPath] +(DT_WSTR, 8) @[$Package::VendorNumber]+"_"+ (DT_WSTR, 20) @[User::ReportDate2]  +"_STK"+".TXT". @ReportDate2 is my variable and this is set using an Output parameter in my SQL stored procedure which I've configured in my OLEDB Source

Comment: what is the original value you mentioned earlier? and where do you set that expression for your Connectionstring? you said the variable value and expression is empty at the start? but you got the expression set? kind confused

Comment: The 'value' and 'expression' settings for the variable is found under SSIS>Variables. They're both blank. There is the option to hardcode the value which would be the 'original' value. I've left this blank. So the original value of the variable is blank at the start.


The expression in my previous comment has been set on the File Connection under the 'Expression' property. I did this by clicking on the 3 dots next to the Expression property, brought up the Property Expression window and set the property dropdown to 'ConnectionString'. I then put that expression into the adjacent box.

Comment: understood, but I mean what do you see now for the value of that file connection? ExtractFolderPath + VendorNumber + `empty` + "_SKT" + ".TXT"?

Comment: Yep, that's what I see now.

Comment: @Brian, you still need to set the `EvaluateAsExpression` to False, because if you set it to `True` without any expression specified, it default to take is as empty value and it will be stick to that value during the runtime, when you create any variable, the default option is `False` which means it will be decided during package execution, which fits your case

Comment: Yep, tried that and still no luck. I checked the Progress tab after it executed and it's still not included the updated variable value in the connectionstring. Any other ideas? The variable is set as String, I can see the variable change in break mode. I think I'll just need to find an alternative way of doing this although it feels like I'm close!

Comment: @LONG: I am a bit taken back. How do you put variable inside parameter? We can put variable inside param, but not opposite. Did i miss something?

Comment: @PrabhatG, I think the `Parameter` op is talking about is the `OUTPUT` for stored procedure, which is taking the output as return parameter, and then parsing that value to variable in SSIS, not the parameters in SSIS, and you are right, we can use variables in parameters in SSIS, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the `delayValidation` property of your connection to `TRUE`.

This way the connection will only be validated and realy connect to the database when you need it and the connectionString expression would already be remplaced with the right value .